# Remove "Designed for iPad" label from the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

My app is designed for iPhone, but it also works for iPad also. In Xcode, I have both iPhone and iPad checked under Deployment Info. But in the website the App Store of my app displays "Designed for iPad" and displays iPad screenshots first (you have to toggle to display iPhone screenshots). How can I changed this to "Designed for iPhone" and display iPhone screenshots first or just remove this completely? I have never specified anywhere that the app was designed for the iPad. This is Apple's doing xD.

I have another app in the App Store that has exact same settings in the Building Settings and General Settings in Xcode, that does not have this label "Designed for iPad" - it doesn't have this "Designed for X" label. I am now thinking that this bug is happening in new apps only. I published the new app with this bug last year. How do I remove this "Designed for iPad" label and display iPhone screenshots first?

Comment: Are you viewing the store on an iPad or on an iPhone?

Comment: I am viewing it on my Mac

Comment: When viewing the App Store apps' webpages on the browser on my Mac, some app pages display iPhone screenshots first and some display iPad screenshots first. Do you know how this can be controlled?

Comment: iOS apps are now visible in the App Store for Apple Silicon Macs unless you have opted out for a particular app in App Store Connect.  The "Designed for iPad" label informs users that this is an iOS app that they can run on their Mac rather than a native Mac app.  If you opt your app out of the Mac store in App Store connect then it will not appear in the Mac App Store at all. See https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/

Comment: My app is designed for iPhone though, not iPad. My app does support iPad, but that's just because why not. Apple though decides to label my app, "Designed for iPad" lmao. How do I prevent Apple from doing whatever it wants?

Comment: If the app is universal (ie supports iPad) then it will have a "designed for iPad" label. There is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: There are other apps that is universal (support iPad) that doesn't have "designed for iPad" - I guess this is because they do not support Apple Silicon on the Mac? It sucks that Apple forces this label then. My app is not designed for iPad; it is designed for iPhone, and it merely works with iPad 

Comment: If you wanted an iPhone only app then you should have released an iPhone only app, not a universal app but you can't go back now.

Comment: By releasing as Universal though it allows people who could benefit from iPad's large screen to have the benefits, even thought it wasn't designed for iPad.

Comment: Hi @coolcool1994, having exactly the same problem. Have an iPhone app that is just supported in iPad. I see other apps that work on iPad and iPhone without that label. I was thinking the problem was in Google Flutter, the language I used for my apps. But apart from this post I cannot find anything on the internet.

Comment: about the part "display the iPhone version first" you can add "?platform=iphone" at the end of your app store product page.

Comment: Hi @coolcool1994,  I created an issue on https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ I keep you updated how it resolves.

Answer (score 30):

In the appstore connect under the Pricing and Availability, I unchecked the Make this app available and now my iPhone screenshots show first and it removes the "Designed for iPad".  It will also take about 1-2 hours to see the change in the appstore.

[image]

[image]

Edit (Thanks to Adam) Also, even when checking this off, the app is still available for iPad as seen in the image of my app when I view it on the app store.

[image]

Comment: And is it  still available for iPad as well ?

Comment: Hi @Wylie Frydrychowicz, worked for me as well. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: But I want to make my app available for Apple Silicon! I think I would rather keep the designed for iPad label and have that Apple Silicon functionality 

Comment: @coolcool1994 yeah, why does this one checkmark have two meanings? There should be a "designed for iPad" and a separate "M1 available" box.

Comment: @user2619824 I wish it was like that. I wonder if Apple realizes yet that not everyone wants their app to say "designed for iPad"

Comment: I tried this and nothing changed. Do I have to wait 24 hours or so?

Comment: @TenDigitGrid I would give it 24 hours or so; if it doesn't change then maybe Apple has changed since I last had to do this. As of now, I haven't worked with iOS apps since I answered this question previously.

Comment: @coolcool1994 me too! any way to uncheck this yet keep it available for mac?

Comment: It works and it took less than an hour to get the label changed from "Designed for iPad" to "Free" which is good enough for me.